# symfony2 test flashbag or session data

Tags: symfony, phpunit, symfony-2.3

How do you test for FlashBag message?

Tried this:

```
public function testInvalidLogin()
{
    $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');
    $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/login');

    $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());
    $form = $crawler->filter('form');
    $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $form->count());

    $form = $form->form();
    $this->assertNotEmpty($form);

    $form['_username'] = 'username';
    $form['_password'] = 'password';

    $this->client->submit($form);
    $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isRedirect('http://localhost/login'));
    $this->client->followRedirect();

    $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');
    var_dump($session->getBag('flashes')->all()); // this print an empty array
}
```

The login controller is sets a flash message 'Bad credentials' but i'm not able to see it during the tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably it's because  after your redirection you are poping flash message eg. somewhere in your template. Flash bag container remove flash message just after you call `get` method (to be specified - removing is implemented IN get method...). If you want just get the message without poping it you should use `peek` method.

I guess that if you move `var_dump` before `followRedirect` then you will get the result you are expecting.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. NO matter where i place it. Before or after redirect. The flash is always empty.

Comment: Actually you're right. just removed the flash get from my view and the message showed up. Thanks!